# Calling angular function from jquery script, and wait for it to finish

Tags: jquery, angularjs, scroll

I want to call `angular` function from `jquery`, each time I press `Enter` in my input tag. then I want to scroll to the bottom of my page. My script is as follow:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".scroll").keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            $.when( angular.element($("#myctrl")).scope().someAngularFunction()).done(function(){
                $("html, body").delay(2000).animate({ scrollTop: $('.bottomOfPage').offset().top }, 2000);
            }
            )}

    });
});
```

This code is working,
but when I remove the delay the scrolling doesn't work. Of course, staying with hard-coded delay is not an option.

Comment: use ng-keyup instead of jquery

Comment: yes, that was my original idea. i used ng-keyup="$event.keyCode == 13 ? SendMessageToTheBot() : null" , and tried to scroll the div insinde this function before exit, but it didn't work. maybe i dont use it the right way.

Answer (score 0):

In the initial of the page-

```
if (false || !!document.documentMode) {
            function CustomEvent() {
                var event = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
                event.initEvent('AngularLoaded', true, true );  
                return event;
            };

            //   CustomEvent.prototype = window.Event.prototype;
            document.angularLoaded = CustomEvent();
        }
        else {
            var event = new Event("AngularLoaded");
            document.angularLoaded = event;
        }
```

And when you want to use angular function after it was loaded

```
document.addEventListener('AngularLoaded', function() {
//your code goes here
```